# Call to a member function getBaseUrl() on null after Shopware update

Tags: php, smarty, shopware

I have done a Shopware upgrade from 5.1.6 to 5.3.7 and now facing a problem which I cannot solve.

`PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getBaseUrl() on null in /html/shopware/var/cache/production_201801171346/templates/.../fbbcad26a2608de331cc46aaf1c82e727c107946.snippet.index.tpl.php on line 444`

The problem occurs at `<?php echo $_smarty_tpl->tpl_vars['Shop']->value->getBaseUrl();?>` in the rendered template file.

The original index.tlp file has this "placeholder" `{$Shop->getBaseUrl()}` at this position.

Any idea what could went wrong?

**Update:** Smarty Debug shows me that the Object at `{$Shop}` is empty.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you would be better reporting this to the Shopware developers

Comment: @RiggsFolly I think he is a shopShopware developer  :p

Comment: Cleared the caches a million times, yes. Updated the question.

Comment: @KevinLieser looks like update failed.. Error looks like you haven't detached shop instance, open shops in base settings and check is there everything okay with hosts/virtual urls e.t.c.

Comment: The database foreign keys and auto increment settings get corrupt on database copy. That was the major problem